# Insert error, Incorrect syntax near '2'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to add information into a table and it comes up with an incorrect syntax.  This is my INSERT Statement:

```
INSERT INTO Exercise 2 (Exercise, [Calories Burned])
VALUES ('Swimming', 500)
```

This is my syntax error message:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '2'.

Comment: This question was caused by a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
INSERT INTO [Exercise 2] (Exercise, [Calories Burned]) VALUES ('Swimming', 500)
```

Table names cannot contain spaces. PUtting the square brackets around it lets you get away with having a space in your table name, just like it does in the "Calories Burned" column.

*(Although it would be better to just rename the objects to remove the spaces:  Exercise2 and CaloriesBurned vs. what you have.  Best practices, normal way to do things, and all.)*

From http://www.isbe.state.il.us/ILDS/pdf/SQL_server_standards.pdf

(Yeah, it's SQL Server, but still, best practice is best practice).

> SQL Server Standards Version 1.5 Shane Lively & Michael Sarsany Page 2
>   of 24
>
> - Use a letter as the first character of the name. (don't start names with underscores or numbers)
> - Limit the use of abbreviations (can lead to misinterpretation of names)
> - Limit the use of acronyms (some acronyms have more than one meaning e.g. "ASP")
> - Make the name readable (they shouldn't sound funny when read aloud).
> - Avoid using spaces in names even if the system allows it.

Comment: Yes please get rid of spaces in object names.  I prefer an `_` to get some visual separation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have table name/column name with spaces like `column a`".
Either say it like `column_a` or `[column a]`

With that you query should look like

```
INSERT INTO [Exercise 2] (Exercise, [Calories Burned])
VALUES ('Swimming', 500)
```

(OR)

```
INSERT INTO Exercise_2 (Exercise, Calories_Burned)
VALUES ('Swimming', 500)
```